# blockdev --setro doesn't work (for me at least)

Tags: linux, block-device

I'm sure I don't understood how blockdev works.

I have mounted a flash drive and it was mapped to `/dev/sdb1`. Then I type in a terminal (as root):

```
root# blockdev --setro /dev/sdb1
root# blockdev --report
```

the report was:

[image]

as you can see, the report said that `/dev/sdb1` is set to read-only (ro). But I'm still able to create files and folders in the flash drive.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a issue with `blockdev` and the drivers used to interact with the HDDs.

*excerpt - [RE: Read-Only Loopback to Physical Disk](http://www.cybercrimetech.com/2010/01/re-read-only-loopback-to-physical-disk.html)*

```
> Another option that I recently found was the 'blockdev' command. You can 
> specify that the blockdev is ro even before mounting.
>
> $ blockdev --report
> $ blockdev --setro /dev/device
>
> But my professor brought up the point - these probably depend on the 
> driver used. Maybe a driver for ntfs totally ignores the ro switch? I 
> don't totally agree that blockdev would be based on the driver, but how do
> you test whether the drive actually is in ro without writing? What if
> it fails?
```

Also this section is relevant:

> Well, the filesystem code will (or *should*) go through the block
>   layer, so using `blockdev --setro` should be effective. However,
>   partitions don't seem to inherit the read-only flag! In other words,
>   if you have a hard disk `/dev/sda` with a single partition `/dev/sda1`,
>   you can do `blockdev --setro /dev/sda` but if you then do 
>   `blockdev --getro /dev/sda1` you'll notice that sda1's read-only flag is not
>   set! I haven't verified yet whether sda1 can be written to in those 
>   circumstances.

So given partitions do not appear to inherit the read/write permissions you'll likely need to use `mount` instead.

*another excerpt*

```
> Then the saving grace - loopback devices. Mount the partition as a file. 
> You don't need to worry about drivers, support, etc.
> To do this use losetup to create a loopback device:
>
> $ losetup -r /dev/loop1 /dev/hda1
>
> This creates a read-only loopback device  pointing to `/dev/hda1`
> Then you can mount the loopback device (read-only if you are paranoid)
>
> $ mount -o ro /dev/loop1 /media/test

> This mounts the loopback device loop1 at `/media/test`. You can then 
> traverse the directory of `/dev/hda1` just like it was mounted.

> According to the PDF document I mentioned above, doing this:
>
> $ mount -o ro,loop /dev/hda1 /media/test
```

Answer (score 1):

`blockdev --setro` must be done before the filesystem is mounted, not after, or you need to do a remount. It says that right in the manpage.  This prevents a more writes than just doing `mount -o ro` but it still doesn't necessarily prevent all low level writes (especially due to software bugs).  Think of `blockdev --setro` as telling the filesystem drivers that the write protect switch/jumper on the drive is flipped (remember when drives/media actually had those) but not actually preventing writes.

`mount -o ro` stops users/programs from creating/changing files but the filesystem driver itself may still do things like update the last mounted date and replay the journal.

readonly loop devices (`losetup -r`) can be used which may be more effective but that only works when filesystem doesn't span devices.

There are linux forensic writeblocker patches that give `--setro` more teeth but it would still be extremely rude to change a device to readonly out from under a mounted filesystem that thinks it can write to the device.  The docs for that tell you more about the issues:
https://github.com/msuhanov/Linux-write-blocker

The manpage neglects to mention that `--setro` doesn't necessarily affect the partition devices (`/dev/sdb1`) when set on the whole disk device (`/dev/sdb`).